# How can I use rest serializer.ValidationError in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and rest_framework. I have a password complexity rules script for 'new user' page.

If my complexity requirements satisfy the needs, it will return true. Else it raises `serialiser.ValidationError`.

I duplicated Django's forget password mechanism to apply my password rules.
When it raises an error, application crashes like below.

```
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
[u"The two password fields didn't match."]
```

Is it possible to use serializer errors as form errors `{{ form.new_password1.errors }}`?

Comment: Django has its own validation error class that you should be using in forms.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write your own custom exception handler to return the error in a preferred format.

The official [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/), at the bottom of the page, says:

> The ValidationError class should be used for serializer and field validation, and by validator classes. It is also raised when calling
>   serializer.is_valid with the raise_exception keyword argument:
>   The generic views use the raise_exception=True flag, which means that you can override the style of validation error responses globally
>   in your API. To do so, use a custom exception handler, as described
>   above.

```
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

> By default this exception results in a response with the HTTP status
>   code "400 Bad Request"

Please read [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) to create your custom handler.